# Vector interactions in R3

Tags: vectors

A line passing through point $P(-4,0,-3)$ intersects the two lines with equations $L1: r=(1,1,-1)+s(1,1,0)$ and $L2: r=(0,1,3)+t(-2,1,3)$. Determine a vector equation for this line.

The position vector for the vector equation of the line meeting the conditions is already given (point $P$), but I can't figure out how to approach finding the direction vector.

Comment: A line through $P$ that also intersects both $L_1$ and $L_2$ must lie in the two planes defined by $P$ and the respective lines.

Answer (score 0):

Any line that passes through $P$ and intersects $L_1$ must (obviously, I hope) lie in the plane defined by this point and line. Similarly, any line through $P$ that intersects $L_2$ must lie in that plane. A line through $P$ that intersects both $L_1$ and $L_2$ must therefore lie in the intersection of those two planes. Find that intersection and (assuming the planes aren’t parallel or don’t coincide), you’ll have your line. As a further hint, the direction vector of this line will be orthogonal to both plane normals.